# MongoDB Atlas - Geolocation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

So I am using Mongodb Compass and trying to test out Geolocation while MongoDB website is very good at terminal coding I need to be able to do the same thing as below in mongoDB atlas - just to make sure the code works.

I plan on using Mongoose as the driver in my react app to fetch the data, however I just thought before I go to far I should see if this is really possible (now I understand Mongodb Compass is different to Mongoose and the query maybe a little different.)

```
db.campaign.find({ location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ 115.880321, 31.9256201], 5 / 3963.2 ] } } })
```

The collection looks like this

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"55cba2476c522cafdb053add"},"location":{"coordinates":[115.880321,-31.9256201],"type":"Point"},"name":"DRN1"}
```

It currently throws an error an does not let me even attempt to search this.

**Query**

```
{ location: { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 115.880321, -31.9256201 ] }, $maxDistance: 5 * 1609.34 } } }
```

[image: Query]

Comment: "currently throws an error " - what the error says?

Comment: @AlexBlex it just highlights the filter red

Comment: What version of Compass? I'm using Version 1.19.12 and it works as-is

Comment: @kevinadi I upgraded to that version and it runs, but returns NULL it should be returning the item in the collection

Comment: @RussellHarrower that's curious. I copied the example document and your query, and got the document back. I even tried changing the query's coordinates a little and varying the maxDistance to verify this is working. I'm using that Compass version and MongoDB 4.2.1. Do you have a `2dsphere` index on the collection?

Comment: @kevinadi I worked it out to be an issue with miles vers KM.